# Rerouting applications' audio to another audio device

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, audio, audio-device

I have [Virtual Audio Cables](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/index.htm) installed, but for some applications it's hard to have them permamnently rerouted through a different audio device, seen as they're missing a specific option to change this (Spotify or your web browser).

I'm wondering if it's possible to reroute another application's output audio-data to a different audio device (From my `SPDIF` to `Realtek Digital Output`, for example.), much like [CheVolume](http://www.chevolume.com/) can do.

Does anyone know if this is at all possible in C# (WinForms?)? And where would I start?

Answer (score 0):

Check this Library by Mark Heath, it is called naudio.

Here is the link : https://naudio.codeplex.com/

You can use this library in C# .net winform based applications.

Its Free.